# Bouguereau painting

Tags: oil-paint

I stumbled upon this photo of Bourguereau:

[image: Bouguereau painting in his studio]

And I have two questions

1) I tried finding the finished painting but I didn't find it. I used this keywords: pregnant, virgin, saint. No clue of the painting. What's the name of this painting?!

2) I can see that the right side of the canvas is already painted. Did Bourguereau painted by grid cells or similar? or is not the same painting?

Comment: Questions about art history (including current art), artwork/artist identification, and art appreciation are not on-topic for this site; we focus on the questions related to hand-making arts and crafts. [See meta](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your picture is incomplete at the top. There are two different canvases superimposed, behind a finished painting and a drawing at the front.

[image]

This is the painting:

[image]

*The Visitation*, «La Visitation», William Bouguereau (1825-1905)

This is the painting behind:

[image]

*The Flight into Egypt*, «La Fuite en Égypte», William Bouguereau (1825-1905)

Both paintings are in the [Saint-Vincent-de-Paul](http://www.patrimoine-histoire.fr/Patrimoine/Paris/Paris-Saint-Vincent-de-Paul.htm) church, Paris